# Turn on/off Android device

Tags: android

I want to implement some code lines that allow Android turn on/off screen like we quick turn on/off device by using Power button. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to lock the device or turn it off?

Comment: The exactly what i want is recall LockScreen display. After turn screen off -> turn it on -> the LockScreen will be displayed. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you are getting a runtime error I posted a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to lock the device not turn it off. To lock the device its a simple code. Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically)

It uses device Policy Manager `lockNow()` method

In case of a RuntimeError use the method described in this question to set permissions

[Android DevicePolicyManager lockNow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560426/android-devicepolicymanager-locknow-problem)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html

To switch off the device:

This is not possible but you can reboot it using PowerManager

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot

Note this requires REBOOT permission and OS may cancel it.

Comment: I am working on Android framework, so maybe there are some differences bwt application and framework. It still doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DevicePolicyManger.lockNow()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29

Comment: After call lockNow(), it throw exception:E/AndroidRuntime( 1159): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: WindowManagerPolicy
E/AndroidRuntime( 1159): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: after that, the device is forced to reboot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do with programming using below code,
**Note: This solution works only on rooted device**

**Shutdown:**

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Restart:**

Same code, just use `"reboot"` instead of `"reboot -p"`.